# How should we hyperlink books?

Tags: discussion, citations

When a question or answer refers to a book, does the following descending preference-order for link destinations make sense? If not, what would be better?

1. Book's site if the full text is freely available on the web
2. Excerpt page on [Google Books](http://books.google.com/)
3. [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/)
4. [Safari](http://safaribooksonline.com/)

Comment: I dislike Google excerpts, since they seem to show/obscure different parts of the book to different people.  Instead of hardcoding Amazon (which one?), an ISBN number is perhaps more useful -- it can go to a service like isbn.nu, or can also be translated to an Amazon id.  Ideal would be some support for ISBN mapping as Wikipedia does.

Comment: Some books have DOIs; in those cases a DOI link would be ideal.

Comment: I think the ordering should be (1) free legal copy (2) DOI if it exists (3) ISBN number if it exists (4) google books (5) whatever commercial site you prefer.

Comment: I posted a feature request to support ISBN tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65537/magic-isbn-markup

Comment: I almost agree with Suresh's ordering (with the possible exception of #5 -- I think we may want to discourage links to commercial sites), but a couple of options are possible once one has an ISBN:
- Wikipedia Book sources: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-7167-9948-0
- Google books: books.google.com/books?as_isbn=0716799480

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a reasonable ordering, although I don't know what "Safari" is.

Comment: Safari is Oreilly's online bookstore. It gives a preview page for most pages in a book, with the bottom ripped off